# Is there a way to check if a Texture2D has unapplied changes?

Tags: unity

In Unity, we can use the `Apply()` function of Texture2D to apply any changes that we've made with `SetPixel()` or `SetPixels()`.

Is there a way to check whether the texture currently has any unapplied changes? I don't see any relevant properties like `IsDirty` or `HasUnappliedChanges`, but perhaps there's a less obvious way to check.

My particular use case is that I have a texture which is normally only used for calculations and does not need to be displayed on the screen, so it's normally not necessary to call `Apply()` after changing the texture. However, I'd like to be able to preview the texture in the Inspector when a particular component is selected, which does require that the texture is Applied. I'm wondering if Texture2D has a built-in way to check for unapplied changes; if not, it won't be difficult to write custom code for tracking this.

Comment: For this use case, since this is only for use in the Editor, why not just write some editor-only code that applies the texture whenever its gameobject is selected?

Comment: @AcmeNerdGames This question is from 21 months ago; I don't even remember what project this was related to, much less the specific reason I needed to check for unapplied changes. I would guess that I was concerned about the performance cost of calling `Apply()`, though I don't usually concern myself over the performance of Editor code...

Answer (score 2):

I've tried `Texture2D.updateCount` but this apparently does not record the count of unapplied changes. So I just use a separate `bool[]` to record which textures I've made changes to. Not as efficient as dealing with all the data directly in `Texture2D` I guess, but it works.